# Submit form in Drupal 6 without going to home page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have embedded a custom search view with `views_embed_view`. The problem is that when the user submits the form, Drupal goes to the site home page.
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [thread in the Views issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/525592) that I think may help. The thread talks about exposed filter forms rather than search, but I think it's the underlying issue. The [suggested fix](http://drupal.org/node/525592#comment-1833824) is to set $view->override_path.